# Isolating a workstation located in an open space office

Tags: noise-reduction, desk

I have a large room in my house, which I use as an open space office where several people are working on their own desk (see image below for an idea of how it looks like).

Several persons make many calls everyday and subsequently disturb the other people. What are some solutions to acoustically isolate their desk, so that they making calls doesn't disturb the others?

My constraints:

- I cannot move his desk
- I cannot ask people to wear headphones or earplugs
- Since I am renting the space, I cannot drill in the floor or ceiling
- I can only modify the desks (or immediate surrounding) of noisy persons

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just put up sound barrier screens around the noisy desks. To make this work you will have to, as a minimum, keep it to one person per desk and where desks are adjacent move them apart enough to allow the barrier screens to stand in between the desks.

Here are a couple of possible examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The clear ones reflect a lot of the sound rather than absorbing it.  Another couple of random examples: http://www.globalindustrial.com/p/office/partitions/panels/freestanding-office-partitions-gray-60-14w-x-72h-238640FGY and http://www.slingsby.com/Office/Furniture/Acoustic-screens/BASE110590Clamp-on-desk-screens--Wave-desktop-screens--red_BASE110590.htm